# Mean value is linear

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification

I consider a finite probability space $\Omega$
I want to show: $$E[a_1X_1+....+a_n X_n] = a_1 E(X_1)+...+a_nE(X_n)$$

When I consider $X_i: \Omega \rightarrow X_i(\Omega) $, I would do the following:
$E[a_1X_1+....+a_n X_n] = \sum_{w \in \Omega} (a_1X_1+....+a_n X_n)(w) P(w)$

$= a_1 \sum_{w \in \Omega } X_1(w)P(w)+.....+ a_n \sum_{w \in \Omega } X_n(w)P(w)$

Is that ok?

Comment: Are you trying to prove that the expectation is linear for this specific case?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur: Yes. Is this ok?

Comment: This seems okay, though it is better to write $\mathbb{P}(\{ \omega \} )$ instead of what you wrote.

Comment: ok:) What is the general case?

Comment: Do you mean how to prove in general that expectation is linear?

Comment: Yes, sorry for my bad english

Comment: The general case can be tricky, and could involve some measure theory construction. However most basic probability courses show linearity for discrete random variables and continuous random variables, which I think would be more suited to what you need. I can added links in an answer should that be what you want.

Comment: It is okay if $\Omega$ is a countable set. If it is not then $\sum_{\omega\in\Omega}\cdots$ has no proper meaning.

Comment: Thank you, you two:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General case:$$\mathbb EaX=\int aX(\omega)P(d\omega)=a\int X(\omega)P(d\omega)=a\mathbb EX$$and:$$\mathbb E[X+Y]=\int [X(\omega)+Y(\omega)]P(d\omega)=\int X(\omega)P(d\omega)+\int Y(\omega)P(d\omega)=\mathbb EX+\mathbb EY$$

This implicates together that: $$\mathbb E\sum_{i=1}^na_iX_i=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\mathbb EX_i$$

---

If $\Omega$ is a countable set and $\wp(\Omega)$ is the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra then $P$ will be a counting measure and the integrals can in that case be written as sums (as you did in your question).

Comment: Thank you very much:) The integral is over $\Omega$ isn't it?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, if no set is mentioned then it is the integral over $\Omega$. Actually integrals do not have a subscript and $\int_A\cdots$ is only an abbreviation for $\int\mathbf1_A(\omega)\cdots$.

Comment: Thank you  very much:)